# local and remote zend server

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-server

I'm learning Zend framework 2 therefore i downloaded the zendstudio IDE included with the zend server as well. I made my little application which is working totally fine on my local zend server. I wanted to try zend PHP cloud as well so i deployed my application there with zend studio. This application didn't work perfectly there. Some of the content is working and the other parts did not load at all only white screen. I checked the server logs and this is what i found there:

> Function Name Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader::loadClass

```
Error Type  E_COMPILE_ERROR
Source File /home/container_name/.apps/http/__default__/0/app/1.0.0/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php

Error String    Can't use method return value in write context
```

I thought that there might be an error during file uploading so i re uploaded the files via an ftp client and the problem is still exists.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of hours of code trace i found the solution:

```
if($this->request->isPost()){
  if(!empty($this->getRequest()->getPost('sg')) <--- this is the line where it dies
```

Remote wasn't liked the `!empty()` so i replaced it with `!=''`